# Is it possible to send emails from Windows8 and IIS 8 using Asp .net

Tags: asp.net, email, windows-8, iis-8

Hi All I want to send emails from my asp .net and I am concerned if it is possible to use my local host IIS8 and windows 8 to send emails.

Note: I do not want to use Gmail Smtp.

Thanks

Comment: Yes,its possible. Whatever Windows OS will be there. With the help of ASP.NET yiou can send the mails. For that purpose you have to buy SMTP Client Service. You will get Username and Password. Then just use SMTP code block to send mails through the application. There are many Hosting Service Provider offers SMTP Client Services.

Comment: Also, if delivrability is a concern (or if you are sending bulk e-mails), you should consider using services like Sendgrid or Mailjet. I do not work for them but I use had the chance to use these SMTP providers and they both have very good quality of service (if you can afford the price).